# html5 video interactive video player

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I have an idea to build an interactive HTML5 video player, I do not want to build something that has already been done but would like to expand on existing ideas. Are there any libraries for building user interactions in HTML5 video, I have looked at popcorn.js, but would like to see other proofs of concept or libraries.

Comment: http://praegnanz.de/html5video/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [H5P](http://h5p.org/interactive-video).

H5P comes as a Drupal module and Joomla extension that allows you to make your videos interactive, directly in your browser. Much the same way as with Popcorn Maker.

Answer (score 0):

In case you woul like to use a more generic framework vi-two.js https://github.com/nise/vi-two could be interesting for you. It has been included in wordpress and mediawiki. It provides many different kinds of video annotations and features that go beyond popcorn.js:

- video zoom
- playlist
- spatio temporal hyperlinks / cyclic links
- temporal tags
- table of contents
- synchronized slides/images